# Write $F_2 + F_4 + F_6 + \cdots +F_{2n}$ as a summation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $F_i$ be the $i$-th Fibonacci number, and let $n$ be any positive integer.

Write $F_2 + F_4 + F_6 + \cdots +F_{2n}$ as a summation.

Show that $F_2 + F_4 + F_6 + \cdots +F_{2n} = F_{2n+1}-1$

So, I understand that to approach the 3nd part in this question, we would likely use induction. However, am confused as to the first part?

Would any one know what to do?

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is probably asking you to write it **precisely**. Every usage of "$\cdots$" is **imprecise**. Only the summation notation, namely using "$\sum$" is precise. Note that it is governed precisely by the rules, given any function $f$ on the positive natural numbers:

> $\sum_{k=1}^0 f(k) = 0$.
>
> $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} f(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) + f(n+1)$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Similarly for summation starting from a different initial index. A rigorous proof for the subsequent parts of the question **must not use** any "$\cdots$", so you will have to use the above properties of the summation notation in your induction proof.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that 
$$
F_1 + (F_2 + F_4 + \ldots F_{2n})
  = (F_1+F_2) + F_4 + \ldots F_{2n}
  = F_3 + F_4 + \ldots + F_{2n}
  \ldots = F_{2n+1}
$$